# Help with plotting graphs

Tags: graphing-functions, desmos

I am using desmos (graphing calculator) but I am open to using other platforms (as long as they are free) if it helps with my issue. I am plotting the following implicit function:
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}} = \frac{1}{(1-x)\frac{100 - \sqrt{x[10\sqrt{x} +500]}}{100} + \frac{ \sqrt{x[10\sqrt{x} +500]}}{100} }$$ where $$0\leq x\leq 1.$$
I needed help with the following:

1. I wanted that when I move my cursor over the plot I could see individual values of $(x,y)$. I faintly remember this being possible in mathematica, is it possible in desmos?
2. How can I mark specific points on my graph? So for example, suppose I want a marker for ($x=0.5$,corresponding $y$) on the plot. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, desmos does not allow you to see individual points on an implicit graph. However, by changing the formula a bit to get an explicit graph, You get [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/smbncx7afg). You still have to click on the graph to see the point, instead of just hovering over the graph. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try **GeoGebra**! This software is **FREE**, and will allow you to have **points on objects**. Beside the small tip over the point (unfortunately my screenshot is without that tip), you will have the info regarding the coordinates in the **Algebra bar** too, and all things are **dynamical**!
https://www.geogebra.org/
[image]